# What happens when electrolytic process rotameters are swapped for a much bigger one?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid, flow-control, bernoulli

electrolytic process rotameter were swapped for much bigger rotameters. Inlet pipes are the still the same. What effect does the  bigger rotameter have in the concentration of catholyte in the cell?

Comment: Probably incorrect results.